# Fire ajax script only after confirmation using bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, confirm

I would like to fire an ajax script via jQuery, but only after confirmation.
I found a nice javascript that works with bootstrap, but can't get it to work.
I can get it work when working with a link or with a submit button, but not with another jQuery event. Here is what I have on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XBM2/3/)

```
$(".deleteit").popConfirm({
    placement: "left"
});

$(".deleteit").click(function() {
    alert("aaa");
});
```

Thanks a lot for any advice!
Any other solution with Bootstrap popovers is appreciated as well!

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpiesnikowski/6XBM2/8/). And quick view:

```
 <div style="width: 500px; text-align:center" id="asd">
    <a href="#15" class="btn btn-danger deleteit" role="button">x</a><br />
    <a href="#16" class="btn btn-danger deleteit" role="button">x</a>
</div>
```

And javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.deleteit').each(function( index ) {
        $(this).popConfirm({
            placement: "left",
            content: '<input class=\'hidId\' type=\'hidden\' value=\'' + $( this ).attr('href') + '\' />'
        });
    });

    $('#asd').on('click','.popover-content .confirm-dialog-btn-confirm', function(e) {
        alert('ajax ID:' + $(e.target).closest('div.popover-content').find('input:hidden').val()); 
        //alert($(e.target).parent().parent().find('input:hidden').val());
         return false;
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Great, that is it! Tnx!

Comment: One problem though :-( I usually give some extra info to the ajax through the id or class, for example: <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger deleteit" id="articleId_5" role="button">x</a> In the ajax I can filter out the ID of the article. But since you now moved the click event to the button in the confirm box, I don't know how to get the ID of the first x-button.

Comment: Next time if you want put also parameter then write it in question. I had answered your question correctly, then you accept the answer. Next you found next problem and unchecked my answer. It's not polite and it's not rather acceptable in SO. I updated my Fiddle.

Comment: Sorry r.piesnikowski, I didn't think of the extra parameter until I started implementing it. How should I then have changed it here on SO?
I appreciate your help alot, so sorry again!

Comment: You can edit your question, then add new comment to notify author of your question. Hope this code will help.